# Why can't I assign a delegate variable to register an event handler?

Tags: delegates

Both of the following work fine:

```
    BindingList<Employee> lstEmployees = new BindingList<Employee>();

    //delegate pointing to an anonymous method
    //----------------------------------------
    delegate void ListChanged(object lst, ListChangedEventArgs args);
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Empno";
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Ename";
        listBox1.DataSource = lstEmployees;

        ListChanged lstchanged = delegate(object lst, ListChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            lblEmpCount.Text = lstEmployees.Count.ToString();
        };

        lstEmployees.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(lstchanged);
    }

    //Anonymous method (with params)
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Empno";
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Ename";
        listBox1.DataSource = lstEmployees;

        lstEmployees.ListChanged += delegate(object lst, ListChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            lblEmpCount.Text = lstEmployees.Count.ToString();
        };
    }
```

But not the following:

```
    delegate void ListChanged(object lst, ListChangedEventArgs args);
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Empno";
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Ename";
        listBox1.DataSource = lstEmployees;

        ListChanged lstchanged = delegate(object lst, ListChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            lblEmpCount.Text = lstEmployees.Count.ToString();
        };

        lstEmployees.ListChanged += lstchanged; //error here
    }
```

If I can assign an anonymous method directly (which is a delegate), why not a delegate variable? I am just trying to understand the difference between all the three methods and why I cannot write the third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define this delegate:

```
delegate void ListChanged(object lst, ListChangedEventArgs args);
```

You could simply use an already defined delegate (`ListChangedEventHandler`) from `System.ComponentModel` namesapce:

```
ListChangedEventHandler lstchanged = delegate(object lst, ListChangedEventArgs args)
{
    lblEmpCount.Text = lstEmployees.Count.ToString();
};

lstEmployees.ListChanged += lstchanged; // no error
```

`ListChanged` event is of type `ListChangedEventHandler`. So you cannot expect it to accept an event handler of another type. The following line is wrong because in your code, `lstchanged` is of your own delegate type (`ListChanged`) while it must me of type `ListChangedEventHandler`.

```
lstEmployees.ListChanged += lstchanged; //error here
```

For more info you can read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/events.aspx).